# UWP app frozen on splash screen when file activated

Tags: c#, file, uwp, activation

I have an interesting problem, hard to debug since it happens when I use file activation to launch this app. 
If I launch the app directly, no problem. If I double-click on the associated file, it hangs at splash screen, not even going past this (setup a debug Breakpoint at `InitializeComponent`, it's not even getting there).

So what I did is: in the Manifest's Declaration tab, I added a File Type Association to the file type I created and ensured "Open is safe" was checked.   Then, used `OnNavigatedTo` override to catch the file name of the file that was used to activate. I get the splash screen and then nothing.

If I just launch the application and open the file from within, everything works. What beats me is that I'm using the exact `OnNavigatedTo` in another app and it works flawlessly.

Here is my OnNavigatedTo:

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var args = e.Parameter as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs;
        if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.File)
            {
                var fileArgs = args as Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileActivatedEventArgs;
                string strFilePath = fileArgs.Files[0].Path;
                var file = (StorageFile)fileArgs.Files[0];
                //MainPlayList is a custom object used to manipulate the playlist of stuff I'm building.
                MainPlayList = new Playlist();
                MainPlayList.InitializePlayList();
                await MainPlayList.AddImageToPlaylist(file);
             }
       }
    }
```

I've checked the package manifest for the working application and this one. Aside from the name, they are identical. Someone mentioned about 18 months ago that it may be related to the Windows version used as minimum. Tried this as well without result.

Comment: Initialize components runs the Load method for the for the class.  A windows form class for example will run the code in the code in the designer.cs file.

Comment: Write System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() in your file activation if and debug your app.

Comment: This was just a breakpoint I used to start tracing where the apllication was going, if anywhere at all. When I launch it, no problem it stops there. When File Activated, I don't even get anywhere. The main window does not even get created.

Comment: try this if (args.Kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.File)
            {System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();...

Comment: @Access Denied, tried this. "Operation Not Supported on This Platform".... Instead i use, from VS2017 Debug/Other Debug Targets/Debug Universal Window App Pre-Launch and then do the file activation.

Comment: @Access Denied, thanks, but it does not even get to the point where I could look at the args. This is what kills me!

Comment: Why don't you override OnFileActivated? protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)

Comment: It could be in Playlist ctor or InitializePlaylist, addImageToPlayList. Prepare sample, which demonstrates the problem and publish a link to source code. Otherwise we could only guess why it may happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the app never leaves the activation handler in `App.xaml.cs` - when the app is not launched yet, and is file activated, it never goes to `OnLauched` and calls [`OnActivated` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnActivated_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_IActivatedEventArgs_), which you can override - and you should - to initialize the root `Frame` and activate the `Window`. Essentially you need to perform the same steps as in `OnLaunched` - so usually you can just turn the initialization into a method and call it from both `OnLaunched` and `OnActivated`.

For an example check the [AssociationLaunching sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching) on GitHub specifically [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/AssociationLaunching/cs/SampleConfiguration.cs#L79) - `OnFileActivated` (which is alternative way to catch file activation).

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }
    }

    var p = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
    p.NavigateToPageWithParameter(2, e);

    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

In case app wasn't started before, the `CreateRootFrame` first creates and sets the root frame so that it is ready. Finally, it uses `Window.Current.Activate()` to make sure the window is active.

Comment: I get it Martin, very useful. Except for the CreateRootFrame which "does not exist in the current context"... I am hosting the override in a  " public partial class App : Application", is it the right class?

Comment: Yes, that is because you have to implement it yourself - see the sample - they also do it manually. The method should do basically the same thing as in `OnLaunched` - check if there is a root frame and if not, create it - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/MultipleViews/cs/App.xaml.cs#L83

Comment: Oh! Missed that! It was in the Apps.xaml.cs.... sorry! Testing it as we speak, many thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Many thanks Martin! Worked flawlessly! Will add my exact code with explanation here a bit later as I've been looking for this everywhere and couldn't find a clear answer. Should have looked at the samples....

Comment: Great, glad it helped :-) . Yes, sometimes the docs should be more detailed. Luckily they are open source, so maybe I will contribute this if I get a moment. Happy coding!